# Scrape a datas using CSS selector (Python, BS4)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am scraping data using CSS selector for the first time.

And there is a problem scraping content of anchor.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://weworkremotely.com/remote-jobs/search?utf8=✓&term=ruby"
wwr_result = requests.get(url)
wwr_soup = BeautifulSoup(wwr_result.text, "html.parser")
posts = wwr_soup.find_all("li", {"class": "feature"})
link = post.select("#category-2 > article > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a[href]")

title = post.find("span", {"class": "title"}).get_text()
company = post.find("span", {"class": "company"}).get_text()
location = post.find("span", {"class": "region company"}).get_text()
link = post.select("#category-2 > article > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a[href]")

print {"title": title, "company": company, "location": location, "link":f"https://weworkremotely.com/{link}"}
```

I want to scrape the content of anchor to make a link of each post. So I put `a[href]`.

But it doesn't work but scrape contents of all subcategory.

What do I have to change to scrape just the content of anchor?

Comment: "scrap" is to discard. The term you are looking for is "scrape" as in "screen scrape".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have correctly selected the jobs of interest from all jobs listed, you need a loop, then extract the first href attribute with substring `-jobs` i.e. `post.select_one('[href*=-jobs]'` during the loop:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://weworkremotely.com/remote-jobs/search?utf8=✓&term=ruby"
wwr_result = requests.get(url)
wwr_soup = BeautifulSoup(wwr_result.text, "html.parser")
posts = wwr_soup.find_all("li", {"class": "feature"})

for post in posts:
    print('https://weworkremotely.com' + post.select_one('a[href*=-jobs]')['href'])
```

To get all the listings on the page switch to:

```
posts = wwr_soup.select('li:has(.tooltip)')
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have a question.
I can get all datas with 
posts = wwr_soup.find_all("li", {"class": "feature"}) 

Why do I need to change it??

Comment: feature doesn't get all the listings. Only the featured.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much.